# Google places autocomplete closes due to billing error android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I am using google places auto-complete. I have enabled the API and also added a billing account. But still, on running the app, the fragment closes on typing an this error is shown

```
I/TAG: An error occurred: Status{statusCode=You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started, resolution=null}
```

The request is registered in the cloud platform but the error percent is 100 %. I do not understand the issue here. If anybody could help?

Comment: Please check once again if the API key you are using is from the same account in which you have enabled billing. This thing happened with me recently.

Comment: Also if any quotas are configured.

Comment: The api I used from the same project i have linked my billing account

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you had included; Please follow this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#top_of_page) as the document will have you follow the four step process in order to use the Google Maps Platform.

Furthermore, if you still have issue after following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#top_of_page) please let us know so we can further investigate the issue.